# Parametrizable JSR-303 validation values

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

I use JSR-303 bean validation and Spring 3 and I need to provide different values for the annotation depending on the use-case.

For example, the value of `min` parameter in `@Size(min=?)` must be 1 for some validation and 5 for another case and I want to read this values from a properties file.

I know the message parameter can be read from `ValidationMessages.properties` file if provided as a key but what about the other parameter?

Answer (score 3):

The values for annotation parameters can only be compile time expressions. This means that for the `@Size(min=X, max=Z)` X and Z must be resolvable at compile time.

Since `min` and `max` are declared as `int` on `@Size`, you are stuck.

If you need different values for `min`, **I personally see two ways of doing it**.

**First**, you could use a grouping on the validators. Use one group for `min=1` and one group for `min=5`. For example, lets consider a `Test` class:

```
public class Test {
  @NotNull
  @Size.List({
     @Size(min = 1, groups = GroupOne.class),
     @Size(min = 5, groups = GroupTwo.class)
  })
  private String prop;

  public String getProp() {
     return prop;
  }
  public void setProp(String prop) {
     this.prop = prop;
  }
}
```

You must declare the groups:

```
public interface GroupOne {}
public interface GroupTwo {}
```

Then create some testing object plus the validator to go with it:

```
Test test = new Test();
test.setProp("XY");

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

Then validate using the groups:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Test>> resultOne = validator.validate(test, GroupOne.class);
Set<ConstraintViolation<Test>> resultTwo = validator.validate(test, GroupTwo.class);
```

First case is valid since `min=1` and `"XY".length() == 2` but second will fail because `min=5`.

This method involves doing the validation manually and I don't think you can just rely on `@Valid` on a `@RequestMapping` annotated method to do the validation (since `@Valid` is just a trigger for the validation with no way of mentioning the required group for validation). Luckly Spring is very flexible and it won't be much overhead to call the validator yourself.

**The second** option I see involves creating your own validation annotation with a custom validator to match. [Here you can find a simple example to get you started](http://blog.m1key.me/2010/07/custom-validation-with-bean-validation.html). With this solution you can declare `min` and `max` as string keys that your validator will resolve in the bundles prior to validation. This solution though is more overhead than the first.

Comment: I do think the custom annotation+validator are the way to here. He could implement a `@DynMin` annotation which would be called like `@DynMin(min = "{my.property.somewhere}") and that used a custom validator class, which would read the property and validate it (using the reference implementation validator, for example).

Answer (score 3):

As outlined by dpb you can use [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) to specify the same constraint with different attribute values.

If you're working with [Hibernate Validator](http://validator.hibernate.org) as BV implementation, based on that you could use the [programmatic API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-specifics.html#programmaticapi) instead of annotations to define your constraints. That way you could retrieve the concrete constraint values at runtime like this:

```
int minValue1 = ...; //read from properties file etc.
int minValue2 = ...;

//programmatically define the constraints for the Test type
ConstraintMapping mapping = new ConstraintMapping();
mapping.type( Test.class )
    .property( "prop", FIELD )
        .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
        .constraint( new SizeDef().min( minValue1 ).groups( GroupOne.class ) )
        .constraint( new SizeDef().min( minValue2 ).groups( GroupTwo.class ) );

//retrieve a validator using the programmatic constraint mapping
HibernateValidatorConfiguration config = 
    Validation.byProvider( HibernateValidator.class ).configure();
config.addMapping( mapping );
ValidatorFactory factory = config.buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```