# Validation annotation and property file

Tags: validation, bean-validation

i have a field in my spring bean (managed bean with jsf) and i am validating on it's length with the @Size annotation using JSR303 bean validation as follows:

```
@Size(min = 7, max = 15, message = "{password.range}")
private String newPassword;
```

and i was wondering how to read the min and max values from property file, please advise.

Comment: this link might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938906/parametrizable-jsr-303-validation-values

Comment: but i am using JSF bean validation.

Comment: JSR303 bean validation is not part of JSF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**New answer**

It is not possible with he standard JSR 303 Validatators. The problem is, that the values in annotations are compile time values, but the values in properties are only available at runtime.

Of course you can write your own JSR-303 Validators that read the value from the properties file while validatation.

So that you can use it this way:

@MySize(minKey = "password.min", maxKey = "password.max", message = "{password.range}")

The `MySizeValidator` uses the `minKey` to read that value from a properties file, and then validate the current value.

Comment: i am sorry i don't get what you are trying to say

Comment: I have replaced my answer by an new one.

Comment: any references please for such custom validator ?

Comment: First git on Google for: "jsr 303 custom validator" http://blog.m1key.me/2010/07/custom-validation-with-bean-validation.html

Comment: Yes. I understand the point. However of this way I have to define the behave of the custom tag, If I would like  using the behave of origina tag it will not work.